# Секция перекрывает ссылку z-index

Tags: z-index, ссылка

Не понимаю, почему секция feynman перекрывает ссылку "подробнее". У секции z-index ниже, чем у ссылки, обоим элементам позиционирование задано. feynman__title и feynman__subtitle позиционировать я не могу - такие условия. Что я делаю не так?

```
.feynman {
  position: relative;
  height: 790px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.feynman__title {
  width: 648px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.feynman__subtitle {
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
  }

.feynman__link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 48px;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feynman__img {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://pngimg.com/uploads/cat/cat_PNG50543.png");
  width: 867px;
  height: 637px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Вот как выглядит: https://codepen.io/kurortnii/pen/GRoqYMb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку у вас перекрывает не `section`, а `h3.feynman__subtitle`. Это происходит потому, что у вас элемент с `position: relative` имеет отрицательный `z-index`.

Comment: Только h3.feynman__subtitle тут не при чём (можно передвинуть ссылку вверх, и она всё равно работать не будет). Ссылку никто не перекрывает. Дело именно в отрицательном z-index'е родительского блока

Comment: Пожалуй соглашусь.

Comment: Ребята, благодарю за ответ. Но если я делаю другие значения z-index у элементов, то у меня либо картинка перекрывает текст, либо картинка уходит за секцию, ЗАТО ссылка становится активной. Запутался в трех соснах, ей-Богу)

Если я правильно понимаю, у заголовка и подзаголовка z-index не ставится, но как бы по дефолту 0.

Comment: Заработало! Ошибка действительно была отрицательном индексе для секции.